# Angular bootstrap carousel digest

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, digest

How can I prevent the carousel firing a full digest cycle and re-running my collection filter each time it slides to a new image.

The plunker below shows shows what I mean if you click an item and watch the log. http://plnkr.co/edit/X062Xr90G807uqURqts9?

```
<carousel disable-ng-animate ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();" interval="5000">
        <slide ng-repeat="photo in object.photos" active="photo.active">
            <img ng-src="{{photo.getUrl({'maxWidth': 350, 'maxHeight': 250})}}" style="margin:auto;">
        </slide>
    </carousel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your collection will not change, you can use one-time-binding:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in ::collection | example" ng-click="setSelected(item)">
```

Here is the [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aR0xKD4HPYInOOepMr8e?p=preview)

But if it's not good for you, you must get into the `carousel` directive, and look if you see `$apply`.
`$apply` will cause to `$rootScope.$digest`and because of this the `filter` will fire for any change.

**EDIT**

After looking on [carousel.html](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/carousel/carousel.html) (the directive template)

you can see `ng-mouseenter="pause()" ng-mouseleave="play()"`.

This is a build-in angular directive and behind the scenes angular use `$apply`, so I can't see any way to avoid a full-digest on carousel directive.

Here is the angular code:

```
forEach(
  'click dblclick mousedown mouseup mouseover mouseout mousemove mouseenter mouseleave keydown keyup keypress submit focus blur copy cut paste'.split(' '),
  function(eventName) {
    var directiveName = directiveNormalize('ng-' + eventName);
    ngEventDirectives[directiveName] = ['$parse', '$rootScope', function($parse, $rootScope) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function($element, attr) {
          // We expose the powerful $event object on the scope that provides access to the Window,
          // etc. that isn't protected by the fast paths in $parse.  We explicitly request better
          // checks at the cost of speed since event handler expressions are not executed as
          // frequently as regular change detection.
          var fn = $parse(attr[directiveName], /* interceptorFn */ null, /* expensiveChecks */ true);
          return function ngEventHandler(scope, element) {
            element.on(eventName, function(event) {
              var callback = function() {
                fn(scope, {$event:event});
              };
              if (forceAsyncEvents[eventName] && $rootScope.$$phase) {
                scope.$evalAsync(callback);
              } else {
                scope.$apply(callback);
              }
            });
          };
        }
      };
    }];
  }
);
```

Comment: unfortunately one-time binding on the collection won't be good, as I need to add / remove / edit items in the collection. I checked the code for the carousel which is on Github https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/carousel/carousel.js but cannot see any use of $appy.

Comment: oh that sucks :( but at least it explains why my filters keep being re-run, thanks so much for the help. I think I will look for some other carousel solution in this case :)

Comment: oh it turns out it is even an issue with this one too https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel

Comment: If you wiil tell me what is the problem with full digest loop, may I can help you...

Comment: No problem with the full digest loop, it just means redundantly re-running all filters just because a single carousel went to the next image.

Comment: one time binding (one way-data-binding) you're talking about is only on angular version > 1.3